# Alexa routine to run at 3am but only if I trigger it during the day

Tags: smart-home, alexa

I want a routine to be triggered at 3am. I already created the routine, but I don't want it to run regularly at 3am, only if I trigger it during the day.

So I want to effectively say "Alexa, enable routine77 at 3am". Or create a routine that waits until 3am then runs routine77.

The problem is, the 'Wait' action waits a set time, not until 3am or even better, 'until two hours before sunrise'.

How do I do this?

Comment: Is it [something like this](https://voicebrew.com/alexa-routine-sunrise-sunset/) that you're looking for?

Comment: @anonymous2 that’s just a schedule. You have to decide in advance which days to run it. I want to be able to kick it off on any random day and not have it run unless I do so.

Comment: Ah gotcha, appologies.